# Unable to stream data from twitter using tweepy in python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""
class listener(StreamListener):
def on_data(self, data):
print(data)
return(True)
def on_error(self, status):
print (status)
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

I have used the consumer keys and access tokens using apps.twitter.com
I am trying this code to stream data from twitter but getting error

[Error screenshot in python 3.4 shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adskO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows an SSL `VERIFY_CERTIFICATE_FAILED` error. Twitter requires that you connect to the streaming API endpoint using TLS.

Comment: I am not aware about what is TLS. Please throw some light over it and help me overcome this problem